# Pairwise Ranking Loss function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am implementing this paper in Tensorflow [CR-CNN](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P15-1061).
The loss function used in the paper has terms which depend on run time value of Tensors and true labels. Tensorflow as far as I know creates a static computational graph and then executes it in a session. I am finding it hard to implement the prediction and loss function mentioned in this paper, since both of them change dynamically at run time.
I tried using tf.cond() in my code but that resulted in 'None' as gradient. Hence my network is not getting trained at all.

```
class_scores = tf.matmul(pooled, W_classes)

n_correct = tf.Variable(0, trainable=True)

for t in xrange(batch_size):
    max_arg = tf.cast(tf.argmax(class_scores[t], 1), tf.int32)
    #true_class = tf.constant(0)
    true_class = tf.cast(tf.argmax(Y[t], 1), tf.int32)

    pred_class = tf.Variable(0,trainable=True)
    value = class_scores[t][max_arg]
    tf.cond(value <= 0, lambda: tf.assign(pred_class, 0), lambda: tf.assign(pred_class, max_arg + 1))
    tf.cond(tf.equal(true_class, pred_class), lambda: tf.add(n_correct, 1), lambda: tf.add(n_correct, 0))

    #print(value)

accuracy = tf.cast(n_correct, tf.float32)/tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)
```

Here I am calculating accuracy by counting the no of correct predictions.

Similar approach for loss function as well:

```
gamma = tf.constant(2.0) 
m_plus = tf.constant(2.5)   
m_minus = tf.constant(0.5)

batch_loss = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True)


for t in xrange(batch_size):
    max_arg = tf.cast(tf.argmax(class_scores[t], 1), tf.int32)
    true_class = tf.cast(tf.argmax(Y[t], 1), tf.int32)

    top2_val, top2_i = tf.nn.top_k(class_scores[t], 2, sorted=True)  

    pred_class = tf.Variable(0, trainable=True)
    true_score = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True)
    neg_score = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True)

    value = class_scores[t][max_arg]

    tf.cond(value <= 0, lambda: tf.assign(pred_class, 0), lambda: tf.assign(pred_class, max_arg + 1))

    tf.cond(tf.equal(true_class, 0), lambda: tf.assign(true_score, 0), lambda: tf.assign(true_score, class_scores[t][true_class-1]))

    tf.cond(tf.equal(true_class, 0), lambda: tf.assign(neg_score, value), lambda: tf.cond(tf.equal(true_class, pred_class), 
                lambda: tf.assign(neg_score, top2_val[1]), lambda: tf.assign(neg_score, value)))

    example_loss = tf.Variable(0.0, trainable=True) 

    tf.cond(tf.equal(true_class, 0), lambda: tf.assign(example_loss, tf.log(1 + tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, m_minus + neg_score)))), 
                    lambda: tf.assign(example_loss, tf.log(1 + tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, m_plus - true_score))) + tf.log(1 + tf.exp(tf.multiply(gamma, m_minus + neg_score)))))
    batch_loss = tf.add(batch_loss, example_loss)

    #print(neg_score)

batch_loss = batch_loss/batch_size
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=lambda_t).minimize(batch_loss)
```

But the network is not getting trained. 
Can anyone suggest how to do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with this code, and as-is it just will not work. I recommend you try using tensorflow eager execution as the conceptual problems you have here do not exist there (you don't need `tf.cond` or `tf.Variable` to solve your problem, for example).

The issue with how this code example is using `tf.cond` is that `tf.cond` is essentially functional (it adds ops to the graph which only get executed when you use the return value of tf.cond). So your code will need to chain the `tf.conds` somehow (probably via `tf.control_dependencies`) to make them execute.

However, you also use `tf.Variables` during your training example. Tensorflow cannot backprop through assignments to `tf.Variable`, so instead you need to replace your calls to `tf.assign` and friends with returning the new value of the variable and using it from python.